# Basis of a closed subspace in a separable Hilbert space

Tags: functional-analysis, hilbert-spaces

Suppose $H$ is a separable Hilbert space and $M$ is a closed subspace of $H$. Suppose $\{u_{j}\}_{j}$ is a countable basis of $H$. Is $\{u_{j}\}_{j}\cap M$ always a basis of $M$? If not, is there any counterexample?

Thanks very much.

Comment: What does it mean to have a basis of a closed subset? Are you talking Schauder or Hamel basis?

Comment: No. Let H=span(e_1,e_2) and M=span(e_1+e_2)

Comment: I mean subspace. I corrected it.

Comment: There doesn't exist a countable (Hamel-)basis of $H$ unless $H$ is finite-dimensional.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $H=L^2[-\pi,\pi]$, which has an orthonormal basis $\{ u_n=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2\pi}}e^{inx} \}_{n=-\infty}^{\infty}$. Let $M$ be the subspace with finite basis $\{ 1,x,x^2,\cdots,x^{N}\}$. Then $M$ is closed. However, $M\cap \{ u_n \} = \{ 1 \}$ is not a basis of $M$ for $N \ge 1$.